# Dashboards do not show content in PBI App

Tags: powerbi

I'm encountering an issue where dashboards fail to display their contents in a Power BI (PBI) app for IT developers and workspace users.  Here are the steps I followed:

1. Created dashboards with visual charts sourced from PBI reports within my workspace.
2. Created a Power BI app and added these dashboards to it.
3. Published the app for access by users.

However, upon accessing the app, I encounter an error message indicating that the dashboard content cannot be displayed.  I've attached a screenshot of the error message for reference.

My suspicion is that the dashboard does not use authenticated user's credentials directly.  Instead it uses the PBI service credentials to access reports and got denied.  How do I fix the access?  Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed dashboards, updated the app, and added dashboards back in. Published it and It works.